# Showing that $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ is quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, geometric-group-theory

I have a question that asks me to show that  $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ is quasi-isometric to $\mathbb{R}$

I have having trouble showing what I have is a quasi isometry. My map is simply:

$f:\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  such that $f(a,b)=a$

This is clearly quasi surjective but in order to show that it is a quasi-isometry i need to consider $d(f((x,y)),d(f(x',y'))$ but I am struggling to come up with bounds on this?

Here I define a quasi-isometry to be a map $f:X\rightarrow Z$ such that we have the following two proerties:

Property 1- Quasi-Embedding

$\exists \lambda, C$ with:

$\frac{1}{\lambda}d(x,y)-C\leq d(f(x),f(y))\leq \lambda(x,y)+C$ for all $x,y\in X$

Property 2- Quasi-surjective

There exists $K\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that for all $z\in Z$ exists $x\in X$ such that $d(f(x),z)\leq K$

Thanks for any help

Comment: Maybe more people will be willing to think about this if you add in your question what is meant by 'quasi-isometric'.

Comment: @drhab I have edited in the definition of quasi-isometric, does this help?

Comment: Which metric do you use on $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$? Probably, $\lambda = 1$ and $C = 2$ work.

Comment: @DanielFischer Just the standard metric (euclidean) I think as it is not specified.

Comment: Okay, that works. $d((x,y),(a,b)) = \lvert x-a\rvert + \lvert y-b\rvert$ would be even simpler, but the Euclidean metric is fine. The abovementioned constants work.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to set $\lambda = 1, C = 2$.  Then use the following:

1) $d\left((a,b),(a,0)\right)$ is at most $1$

2) $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$ is an isometry

3) The triangle inequality

This should get you the Quasi-Embedding property you need.

Comment: $\lambda = 1$, $C = 1$.

Comment: @Did $C=1$ works, but it's even easier if you set $C=2$, because then you can connect any two points in $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ directly to the corresponding points in $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$, which connects them via a 3-part path (down to $\mathbb{R} \times \{0\}$, along it, and back up).  Of course, it's still pretty easy to use the Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The map $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times [0, 1]$ such that $x \mapsto (x, y_0)$ for a fixed $y_0 \in [0, 1]$ is a quasi-isomorphism with $\lambda =1$ and $C=0$.

Remember from Nowak and Yu's book, Large Scale Geometry, that $X$ and $X\times Y$ are quasi isometric which $X$ is a metric space and $Y$ is a bounded metric space (example 1.3.5).